# Time dependent URL redirection script, should work differently on Monday - How?

Tags: php, datetime

This is the top part of a script I am using for redirection.
It connects to two txt based databases depending on time and redirects the user to a particular link.
There are two databases
'db1.txt' and 'db2.txt'
I only want to use the 'db2.txt' on Mondays.
All other day it should work normally, but on Mondays only, it should not change to urls1.txt.
How can I achieve that ?

```
$time = date("Hi", time());


if ($time >= 2224 && $time <= 2359)
{
    $db = "db1.txt";
}
elseif ($time >= 0000 && $time <= 729)
{
    $db = "db1.txt";
}
else
{
    $db = "db2.txt";
}
```

Edit:
I am from India, and I am using server time in my script to avoid more complications. The script is designed to load db1.txt from 9:00AM to 6:00PM IST, and db2.txt from 6:01PM to 8:59AM. So using the "if (date('N') !=1 " wont work. I will need to change the time-zone as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add this condition  `!= monday` like this

```
$time = date("Hi", time());


if (date('N') !=1 && $time >= 2224 && $time <= 2359)
{
    $db = "db1.txt";
}
elseif (date('N') !=1 && $time >= 0000 && $time <= 729)
{
    $db = "db1.txt";
}
else
{
    $db = "db2.txt";
}
```

**note** : `N`  ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0)

Comment: I got it, thanks, I just updated the time zone as well. It actually make the script simple.

Comment: i too from India and also next to your state. cool!!! glad to help you .@MalavikaP

Answer (score 0):

Check the argument documentation for the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.  With:

```
date('N');
```

you should be able to check if it's Monday and execute your desired code conditionally, ex.:

```
if(date('N') === 1){
}else{
}
```